# ICU4C equivalent of LocaleMatcher

Tags: c++, internationalization, icu, cldr, icu4c

Does ICU4C have any equivalent to ICU4J's [`LocaleMatcher`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/LocaleMatcher.html), for finding the best match between an application's set of supported locales and a user's list of preferred locales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICU 65 (October 2019) will have a C++ LocaleMatcher. I merged this into the master branch today: https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/pull/714

Answer (score 1):

There's an [existing feature request](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-9695) to port `LocaleMatcher` to in C++. In the *C* API, there's [`uloc_acceptLanguage`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uloc_8h.html#a3b9d2f95d1a205665a0597762fd08ca2), but it's less convenient to use.